# Simple Pulling Mechanisms and Approaches in Enterprise Platforms

Tags: integration, esb, pull

This question is not directly on code or to debug rather more on a solution.

Working on defining a solution around the following requirements:

1. Consume data from diverse upstream systems.
2. Publish the data to the subscribers.

Straight forward to some extent because I need to identify the suitable pub/sub mechanisms which best suites for enterprise platform, but point 1 is where I am facing some  complexity because I am confused about whether to go for push approach or pull approach.

For a push approach, what I can think of is to use MQ as a broker in between and define the standard message format for the upstream systems. But the main drawback with this approach is, there will be a some level code changes at the upstream systems.

So, why not the pull approach? If this question arises, then I don't have the right answers because I could not think of any way to pull the data from the source systems without the native services available with source systems. Please suggest some of the approaches best suited for this problem.

Please do not suggest on ESB kind of solutions because, this is a simple case which we are trying to solve and hence ESB will be an overkill. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Well if you cannot think of a way to achieve pull approach it is quiet clear that you can only go for a push approach. Just a suggestion but go look at the Apache Camel project it is a EIP library not an ESB and has been created for this type of problem.

Comment: Thanks Namphibian. Even though I had Apache Camel as one of the option for a proof of concept, got a new lead on solving a certain specific problem. Thanks again.